Value to pass to filter function in dplyr to obtain everything
Is there a value or function you can pass to dplyr’s filter function to obtain all rows (i.e. make the function do nothing and return the original data frame)?
df %>%
    filter(col_name == what_do_I_put_here?)

To explain why on earth I’d want to do this…
I am plotting a graph, to be faceted into multiple horizontal groups (specified by the food_type column in the example below). I would also like the code to spit out separate individual graphs for each food_type. To save writing out the same code multiple times, I’ve decided to do this in a loop. It would look something like:
Example data
greengrocer_stock <- tibble(food = c("Strawberry", "Plum", "Orange", "Parsnip", "Lettuce", "Carrot"),
                            food_type = c("Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Vegetable", "Vegetable", "Vegetable"),
                            count = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 8))

Combining into a loop
food_types <- c("Fruit", "Vegetable")

for(type_of_food in food_types){

  greengrocer_stock %>%
    filter(food_type == type_of_food)

     ### Then go on to produce the graphs here
}

I would like to be able to add a third value to the food_types vector which selects everything, a bit like everything() in dplyr's select function.' However, this does not work here:
greengrocer_stock %>%
  filter(food_type == everything())

     Error in `filter()`:
     ℹ In argument: `food_type == everything()`.
     Caused by error:
     ! `everything()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
     ℹ See ?tidyselect::faq-selection-context for details.
     Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Filtering manually
It's of course possible to return all data manually (by not running the filter function at all), but ideally I'd like to pass an argument to filter to get it to return all rows.
greengrocer_stock %>%
     filter(food_type == "Fruit")       # Returns fruit rows

greengrocer_stock %>%
     filter(food_type == "Vegetable")   # Returns vegetable rows

greengrocer_stock                       # Returns all rows

Using %in%
Another idea was to use %in% with a vector containing all values of food_type, as here:
all_food_types <- unique(greengrocer_stock$food_type)

greengrocer_stock %>%
      filter(food_type %in% all_food_types) 

But I'm not sure how I'd combine this into a vector to loop over, as a loop would loop over each element of all_food_types individually.

If you control the code then expand the filter as shown.  It checks if the food_type column in greengrocer_stock equals the iteration variable of the for.  It also matches if the iteration variable in the for is All. (Not shown but you might consider using f for the iteration variable name since the existing names are so similar it can be a bit confusing.)
food_types <- c("Fruit", "Vegetable", "All")
for(type_of_food in food_types) {
  greengrocer_stock %>%
    filter(food_type == type_of_food | type_of_food == "All") %>%
    print
}

giving
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  food       food_type count
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 Strawberry Fruit         2
2 Plum       Fruit         5
3 Orange     Fruit         3
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  food    food_type count
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 Parsnip Vegetable     7
2 Lettuce Vegetable     3
3 Carrot  Vegetable     8
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  food       food_type count
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 Strawberry Fruit         2
2 Plum       Fruit         5
3 Orange     Fruit         3
4 Parsnip    Vegetable     7
5 Lettuce    Vegetable     3
6 Carrot     Vegetable     8


We can use unique and %in% together and save the object in list so that we can have more than 1 value in the loop.
food_types <- unique(greengrocer_stock$food_type)
new_food_types <- c(as.list(food_types), list(food_types))
new_food_types 
#[[1]]
#[1] "Fruit"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Vegetable"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Fruit"     "Vegetable"

Now use new_food_types in the loop
for(type_of_food in new_food_types){
  greengrocer_stock %>%
    filter(food_type %in% type_of_food) %>%
    print
  
  ### Then go on to produce the graphs here
}

This would result into the following output :
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#  food       food_type count
#  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Strawberry Fruit         2
#2 Plum       Fruit         5
#3 Orange     Fruit         3

# A tibble: 3 × 3
#  food    food_type count
#  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Parsnip Vegetable     7
#2 Lettuce Vegetable     3
#3 Carrot  Vegetable     8

# A tibble: 6 × 3
#  food       food_type count
#  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Strawberry Fruit         2
#2 Plum       Fruit         5
#3 Orange     Fruit         3
#4 Parsnip    Vegetable     7
#5 Lettuce    Vegetable     3
#6 Carrot     Vegetable     8


You can use split as follows:
c(list(greengrocer_stock), split(greengrocer_stock, greengrocer_stock$food_type))

Output:
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  food       food_type count
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 Strawberry Fruit         2
2 Plum       Fruit         5
3 Orange     Fruit         3
4 Parsnip    Vegetable     7
5 Lettuce    Vegetable     3
6 Carrot     Vegetable     8

$Fruit
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  food       food_type count
  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
1 Strawberry Fruit         2
2 Plum       Fruit         5
3 Orange     Fruit         3

$Vegetable
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  food    food_type count
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 Parsnip Vegetable     7
2 Lettuce Vegetable     3
3 Carrot  Vegetable     8

